# How can I pass a html form? nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, authentication

At the moment I try to reach a Website (https://bracke-igs.de/iserv). Here there is a form a need to pass to reach data on the website.

My problem is that I dont manage to pass the form. Any hint?

Thx for reading && thx for help!

```
var request = require('request');
request = request.defaults({ jar: j })
request.post('https://bracke-igs.de/iserv/login_check?_username=test&_password=test')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below snippet should help. For more options please refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms). And refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#examples) for more sample implementations of `request`.

```
request.post('https://bracke-igs.de/iserv/login_check').form({_username:'test', _password='test'})
```